# AMQP Message properties not being published to RabbitMQ hub

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-c

I have used vcpkg to build rabbitmq-c as described in the https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c build instructions:

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
cd vcpkg
./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
./vcpkg integrate install
./vcpkg install librabbitmq
./vcpkg install boost
```

Then I built https://github.com/alanxz/SimpleAmqpClient (latest release version 2.5.1)

The problem that I am facing is that the message properties like CorrelationId, Type, etc. are not being sent to RabbitMq hub. The same code was working previously before I upgraded to latest release.

Here is the code that I am using:
I publish the message using the following code:

```
void RabbitMqNode::SendResponse(google::protobuf::Message *response, NodeEnvelope *envelope, std::map<string, string> headers)
{
    auto message = GetBasicResponseMessage(response, envelope, &headers);
    auto returnAddress = envelope->returnAddress;
    channel->BasicPublish(std::string(), returnAddress, message);
}

AmqpClient::BasicMessage::ptr_t RabbitMqNode::GetBasicResponseMessage(google::protobuf::Message *response, NodeEnvelope * envelope, std::map<string, string>* headers)
{
    auto message = GetBasicMessage(response, headers);
    message->CorrelationId(envelope->corelationId);
    return message;
}

AmqpClient::BasicMessage::ptr_t RabbitMqNode::GetBasicMessage(google::protobuf::Message *inputMessage, std::map<string, string> *headers)
{
    auto body = serializer.SerializeMessageToJson(inputMessage);
    return GetBasicMessage(inputMessage, body, headers);
}

AmqpClient::BasicMessage::ptr_t RabbitMqNode::GetBasicMessage(google::protobuf::Message *inputMessage, std::string messageBody, std::map<string, string> *headers)
{
    auto name = GetMessageName(inputMessage);
    auto message = AmqpClient::BasicMessage::Create(messageBody);
    message->DeliveryMode(AmqpClient::BasicMessage::delivery_mode_t::dm_nonpersistent);
    message->ContentType(MIME_JSON);
    message->Type(name);
    message->AppId(nodeId);
    auto headerTable = message->HeaderTable();
    InitializeHeaders(&headerTable, headers);
    message->HeaderTable(headerTable);
    message->Timestamp(utility.GetCurrentUnixTimestampMilliseconds());

    return message;
}

void RabbitMqNode::InitializeHeaders(AmqpClient::Table *headersTable, std::map<string, string> *headers)
{
    if (headers->empty())
    {
        return;
    }
    std::map<string, string>::iterator it = headers->begin();
    while (it != headers->end())
    {
        auto key = (std::string)it->first;
        auto value = it->second;

        headersTable->insert(std::pair<string, string>(key, value));

        // Increment the Iterator to point to next entry
        it++;
    }
}
```

Note: The body of the message and the headers are being sent without any issues.

Observation: Only the AppId property is sent correctly if I don't initialize the headers; but if I initialize headers, then except the headers no other property is sent to the hub. The body is always sent correctly; no problem with that.

Could some one please identify the mistake?

PS: I have created a issue in the Git repo for this: https://github.com/alanxz/SimpleAmqpClient/issues/287

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed. The latest release (SimpleAmqpClient v2.5.1) has this issue but it is fixed later on in the master branch. More details here: github.com/alanxz/SimpleAmqpClient/issues/287